# Unable to format USB after unplugging while formating

Tags: partitioning

I unplugged the USB while formatting. Now I can not format it again, not with gparted nor with `fsck`.

```
fsck from util-linux 2.39.1
e2fsck 1.47.0 (5-Feb-2023)
fsck.ext2: Read-only file system while trying to open /dev/sdb1
Disk write-protected; use the -n option to do a read-only
check of the device.
```

`lsblk`

```
sda      8:0    0 238.5G  0 disk
├─sda1   8:1    0   500M  0 part
├─sda2   8:2    0   100G  0 part /var/lib/snapd/snap
│                                /
└─sda3   8:3    0   138G  0 part /home
sdb      8:16   1     8G  1 disk
└─sdb1   8:17   1     8G  1 part
```

Gparted is saying `Can't write to /dev/sdb , because it is opened read-only`

Comment: Why ask here?  I see nothing currently on-topic for this site as no OS/product/release is mentioned; refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic ; if you didn't (correctly) actually *dismount* the USB & you're still using the same session, it may be influenced by *cached* data that no longer applies... I'd suggest *dismount* correctly & re-try, though actual OS/release details if known may alter this view.